# How to pass multiple parameters with using RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I did with below code for passing single parameter.

```
lazy var priceListData: Observable<FoodPrice> = {
        return self.foodNamesparams1.asObservable()
                   .flatMapLatest(ApiCallViewModel.foodList(_:))
}
```

But I don't know how to pass multiple parameters..
If I need to pass `foodNamesparams1`, `foodNamesparams2` to `ApiCallViewModel.foodList`
How can I do it with RxSwift?

`foodNamesparams1` and `foodNamesparams2` both are `BehaviorRelay`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095592/rxswift-use-zip-with-different-type-observables

Comment: This might be helpful: https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely want to combine the parameters first, most likely via `combineLatest` or `zip`.

This will looks something like this

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    foodNamesparams1.asObservable(),
    foodNamesparams2.asObservable()
  )
  .flatMapLatest(ApiCallViewModel.foodList)
```

CombineLatest will not emit anything unless both combined observables have emitted at least once - and then it will commit on any update of either combined observable.

Check out the combining section here
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining to find the best suited combination method

Comment: Oh! I got it! Thank you! :-)